# Use multiple map controller wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a pivot App on windows phone 8, with 2 pages. I want to display 2 maps (1 on each page).
On the first page, the map is displayed well.

When I put the second map, my app crashed, and I see that my second map controller is set to null.

Why the second map controller is null ?

Comment: Can you add some exceptions which you get?

Comment: what kind of exceptions do you get?

Comment: Sure. here's all the exception : `+  $exception {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MyProject.MainPage.webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException} ` This execption occures when I want to add a Layer to my map, and when I put my mouse over "my_map", it says it is null

Comment: OK. I removed my app from my device, then run it again, and now it works... Do you know why ? and how can I fix it ?